# Display SpriteClass using Font-Awesome in Kendo Panel Bar

Tags: kendo-ui, font-awesome, kendo-panelbar

I'm having a trouble on displaying `<i>` in Kendo Panel Bar cause it only uses `<span>` and `<img>`

Is it possible to use Font Awesome in Kendo Panel Bar?

Code for displaying `<span>`

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">

            <h4>PanelBar with sprites</h4>

            <div id="panelbar-sprites"></div>

        </div>

        <script>
            $("#panelbar-sprites").kendoPanelBar({
                dataSource: [{
                        text: "Brazil", spriteCssClass: "brazilFlag", items: [
                            { text: "History", spriteCssClass: "historyIcon" },
                            { text: "Geography", spriteCssClass: "geographyIcon" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: "India", spriteCssClass: "indiaFlag", items: [
                            { text: "History", spriteCssClass: "historyIcon" },
                            { text: "Geography", spriteCssClass: "geographyIcon" }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Netherlands", spriteCssClass: "netherlandsFlag", items: [
                            { text: "History", spriteCssClass: "historyIcon" },
                            { text: "Geography", spriteCssClass: "geographyIcon" }
                        ]
                    }]
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example dojo using random font awesome sprites [example dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ECOPe)

All you need to do is include the font awesome css (either locally or from the cdn) and then using the font awesome naming convention e.g. `fa fa-circle-stop` etc it will be included as part of the header.

The example you have provided I assume is from the demo site and if you look further down (in the css declaration section) you will see that it loads a sprite file and then absolute positions the images for the flags.

If you need any more info then let me know.

Comment: Hi! It will still display as boxes and it still uses `<span>` of course.. but whenever I change it as `<i>` (in inspect element) the icon will display

Comment: Hi! @David Thanks I already get it. I had an error in my `css` that the metroui will override the font-awesome